# Parent object not updated when I update using child object

Tags: apex, soql, content, contentdocument

I have a few contentfolders. I have a linking object(Asset_DMSFolder__c) to relate these contentfolders to records. Can't we update the parent object properties via child objects? Please advise.

```
List<id> lstAssetIds= new List<id>();
lstAssetIds.Add('aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa');
List<Asset_DMSFolder__c> AssetFolders = [select Id,DMS_Folder__r.Name,Asset__r.Name,Asset__r.Id from Asset_DMSFolder__c where Asset__c IN: lstAssetIds];

AssetFolders[0].DMS_Folder__r.Name = 'renameusingchild';
update AssetFolders;
    // the above update does not change the folder name to renameusingchild
System.debug([select Id,DMS_Folder__r.Name,Asset__r.Name,Asset__r.Id from Asset_DMSFolder__c where Asset__c IN: lstAssetIds][0].DMS_Folder__r.Name);

ContentFolder cf = [select Id from ContentFolder where Id =:AssetFolders[0].DMS_Folder__c ];
cf.Name =  'testdirectobjupdate';
update cf;
System.debug([select Id,DMS_Folder__r.Name,Asset__r.Name,Asset__r.Id from Asset_DMSFolder__c where Asset__c IN: lstAssetIds][0].DMS_Folder__r.Name);
//the above update works
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update the parent record by using child record by following `update` query

```
 update AssetFolders[0].DMS_Folder__r;
```

Refer https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SObjects_field_relationships.htm

For collection:

```
List<ContentFolder> contentFolders = new List<ContentFolder>();
for(Asset_DMSFolder__c asset:  AssetFolders){
    asset.DMS_Folder__r.Name = '' //put the value
    contentFolders.put(asset.DMS_Folder__r);
}

update contentFolders;
```

Comment: As per the Salesforce documents, it is working

Comment: this one works, but the problem is that I need to update the collection. I am trying to update more than one folder names with different names.

Comment: You want to update `DMS_Folder__r` for all the `AssetFolders` using a loop?

Comment: Hi. Yes. But updating this using a forloop might reach the DML statement limit.

Comment: Updated the code for List.

Comment: Please defract your downvote

Comment: sorry, it was a mistake. I have never voted before, so I did not know. I was wondering why it was downvoted.